# Why I cant programmatically change the width of UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am trying to programmatically change the width of a UITextField using the following code:

```
myText.frame = CGRectMake(myText.frame.origin.x, myText.frame.origin.y, 280 ,myText.frame.size.height);
```

The code above is executed on a "touch up inside" button action.

myText has its border style property set to UITextBorderStyleNone

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: First of all : are you sure that 280 isn't your default width ? It might happen ! Else, do you have auto layout enabled maybe ? Some constraints might generate troubles with frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to set frame programmatically just disable the autolayout for your .xib

Comment: Autolayout was the problem. Is there a way to have both (autolayout and the abillity to set gram in code)?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that either you never linked the IBAction to the UIButton, or there is no IBOutlet pointing to the UITextField.

You can verify that the IBAction is getting called on button press simply by adding an NSLog statement to it, or you can check that both are linked from the "Connections Inspector" in Interface Builder.

**Side note** Since your text field is set to have no border, it is possible that you just can't tell it is growing. To verify, I would trying setting the text field's background color to something obvious.